# Waze, notification when someone pin traffic accident

Tags: notifications, traffic, waze

my client has a small fleet of vehicles and he asked me to figure out how to get waze accident data sent to his phone. He said someone who is a competitor has alerts set up when there is an accident reported to waze within a certain mile radius, they get a notification that shows them a list of all the accidents and addresses.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only legal way of retrieving the alerts information from Waze would be through [the Waze for Cities program](https://www.waze.com/ccp). The Waze for Cities program is completely free and allows organisations to obtain certain types of information from Waze (alerts, traffic jams, unusual traffic notifications, ...). In return, these organisations are expected to give certain types of information back to Waze (road closures, alerts, ...). But as the name implies, this program is meant for public instances, not private companies. The past couple of years, Waze has no longer allowed any private companies to access this information as those companies generally give little in return for the data.

An illegal way of retrieving these alerts for you would be to scrape the data from [the Waze livemap](https://www.waze.com/live-map/directions?overlay=false). I'm sure you'll understand why I'm not going to give any further details on how to do that though.

It's a long shot, but Waze also has a bunch of Twitter accounts that send unusual traffic alerts in their area. [There aren't that many accounts though](https://twitter.com/i/lists/204210827/members), so this is quite unlikely to work for you.

I know it won't help with creating alerts, but just for being as complete as possible in my answer I'd like to mention the ability to embed the Waze livemap on a web page. it is possible to generate the code for this via the livemap, but manually changing the parameters isn't that hard:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.waze.com/iframe?zoom=15&lat=51.493194&lon=-0.013390&ct=livemap" width="600" height="450" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply and detailed comment. I would like to as you what you think about integromat and getting the alerts through telegram ? Thanks again

Comment: @SrdjanVujicic I'm afraid I have no experience with either integromat or telegram, so I'm of little help there.